# Spreadsheet/Excel array functions that compare and validate values

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

I got this dataset

```
ID  fruit   price
1   apple   10
2   apple   50
3   apple   100
4   banana  10
5   banana  20
6   banana  50
```

and would like a (set of) forumla(s) that go through the rows and output the row for each fruit that has the highest price.

In e.g. PHP I would do something like this

```
foreach $array as $row{
  if in_array( $row[fruit] ){
    /* check if current $row[price] for current $row[fruit] is larger than existing post. If yes replace */
  }
}
```

How would I do that in Google Spreadsheets / Excel?

Comment: Is your dataset sorted into ascending order of fruit and then price?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Excel with array formulas (so you enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)...
If your fruit is in `B` and price in `C` your array formula in `D2` would be

```
=C2=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$7=B2,$C$2:$C$7,0))
```

This will give you `TRUE` or `FALSE` for whether that row has the highest price for that fruit.

It works by doing an `IF` on the array of fruits (rows 2 to 7 - you can make it longer) being the same as the current fruit - if it is the same, return the price, otherwise 0. We then get the `MAX` and compare it to the current row's price.

Good luck!

Comment: Good answer I think. In the particular case shown, where the data are in order and there is a single maximum price for each fruit, you could just put =B2<>B3 in D2, but Captain's answer is much more general.

Comment: @Joseph Did this work for you? Feel free to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a quick VBA macro that you could use in excel that will output the fruit with the highest price.

The macro converts the table of fruit toa an array and then loops through the array to find the fruit with the highest value, before outputting it to the sheet. This macro relies on the table of fruit being positioned in columns A to C.

```
Sub getMaxPriceFruit()

'put data table into an array
Dim dataTableArray() As Variant
dataTableArray = Range("A2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'loop through the aray looking for the largest value
'capture array index in variable when largest is found
Dim maxArray(1 To 1, 1 To 3) As Variant
maxArray(1, 1) = 0
maxArray(1, 2) = ""
maxArray(1, 3) = 0

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(dataTableArray)

    If dataTableArray(i, 3) > maxArray(1, 3) Then
        maxArray(1, 1) = dataTableArray(i, 1)
        maxArray(1, 2) = dataTableArray(i, 2)
        maxArray(1, 3) = dataTableArray(i, 3)

    End If

Next i


'output the fruit with the max value
Range("F2").Value = maxArray(1, 1)
Range("G2").Value = maxArray(1, 2)
Range("H2").Value = maxArray(1, 3)


End Sub
```

The limitation of this script is that if there are two fruit with an equal max value, the first fruit in the list with that value will be selected as the winner. If you would like the additional code to output multiple fruits if they have the same max value I can provide, but put simply you could utilise the maxArray array to capture all of the top ranking fruits and then loop through this array to output them all in one go.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table with `fruit` for Rows and `price` for Values (Summarise by: MAX) may serve.